# How to view all errors in the project

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, goland

I would like to see all compilation/syntax errors in a single list, so it would be easier to understand what should be fixed. I would describe it like something similar to vim`s quickfix window.

Currently I'm using `Analyze -> Inspect Code...`, but it lists *all* inspections, which could be sometimes too much. I can probably configure different profiles for inspections and switch between them, but probably there is some other approach which I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run Build | Build Project, the Messages toolwindow will display the list of all compilation errors.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I don't really want to build the project and we're not using standard tools (you might understand that :) ) But I'll accept this answer,  as for everybody else this should be the correct way.

Answer (score 3):

The question is unclear so I'll answer the two possible questions.

For IntelliJ IDEA you can use Build | Build Project.

For Go functionality / GoLand, you cannot use this, it's not supported. Follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4618 for updates there.